# Capturing special key presses (shift, alt) of the Soft / OnScreen keyboard

Tags: android

I am trying to capture the key-press for the shift or alt keys and it seems to work just fine with the physical keyboard.  Unfortunately when I test the same code with the onScreen keyboard it doesn't respond at all (I've tried a 2.1, 4.03 emulator and 2.3 physical device).

This seems to be a platform issue that probably has no workaround, but as a last ditch effort I wanted to post the question here to see if anyone has found one (I am willing to entertain any ideas).

Thanks!

**Edit to clarify my point:**  I tried putting a breakpoint on the " if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) " line, and it will always stop if I press the shift of the physical keyboard, but never when I press the shift of the onScreenKeyboard.  So, the problem is that onKey is not being executed for all keypresses of the onScreenKeyboard.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    mEditText1.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        Toast.makeText(IMETestActivity.this, "Enter was consumed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_LEFT_ON:
                    case KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_RIGHT_ON:
                        Toast.makeText(IMETestActivity.this, "Meta Shift was consumed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT:
                        Toast.makeText(IMETestActivity.this, "Shift was consumed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the keycode whenever a key is pressed to make sure that the event is registering.  If it is, just add that code to your switch statement.

For example, something like System.out.println(keyCode) at the beginning of your onKeyListener.  You can view the output using LogCat.

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint on the " if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) " line, and it will always stop if I press the shift of the physical keyboard, but never when I press the shift of the onScreenKeyboard.  So, the problem is that onKey is not being executed for all keypresses of the onScreenKeyboard.